# TS2339: Property 'showNewCustomerFields' does not exist on type '{ newCustomer(owner: any): void; }'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3

I'm new to both vue an ionic and i am unable to figure out why i am getting this TS2339 error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

```js
  data() {
    return {
      owner: "default",
      showNewCustomerFields: false,
      newCustomerName: "",
    };
  },
  method: {
    newCustomer(owner) {
      //console.log(owner);
      if (owner === "new") {
        this.showNewCustomerFields = true;
        // console.log(showNewCustomerFields);
      } else {
        // console.log(showNewCustomerFields);
        this.showNewCustomerFields = false;
      }
    },
  },
```

Comment: Try to provide minimum reproducable example in ts playground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Vue [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#defining-vue-components):

> To let TypeScript properly infer types inside Vue component options, you need to define components with `defineComponent` global method:

So your code should look like this:

```js
// MyComponent.vue
import {} from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      owner: "default",
      showNewCustomerFields: false,
      newCustomerName: "",
    };
  },
  method: {
    newCustomer(owner) {
      if (owner === "new") {
        this.showNewCustomerFields = true;
      } else {
        this.showNewCustomerFields = false;
      }
    },
  },
})
```